# Getting the $rank variable and updating it in the table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, variables, rank

I'm having trouble getting the ranked value for a variable and updating it to a column. Basically what I mean is that below I have a code that selects column "bankaccount" from table "bank" and i'm ranking the bank accounts based on the bank balance. How would I be able to select to update the column "bankaccountranking" based on what the rating each account got.

Example: Ranked 1 bank account is John Smith. How would I write a code so that I UPDATE John Smith's "bankaccount ranking" column in table "bank"? I tried to update using the $rank variable but that doesnt work.

Below is the code: (thanks in advance):

```
$sessionid = $_SESSION['uid'];
$info = $conn->prepare("SELECT `bankaccount`,`bankbalance` FROM `bank` WHERE           id:id      ORDER BY `bankbalance` DESC");
$info ->bindParam(':id', $sessionid , PDO::PARAM_INT);
$info->execute();


 $rank = 0;


while ($userinfo = $info->fetchobject()) {
$rank++;
echo "<b>$rank</b> . $userinfo->bankaccount &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp <b>Bank                    Balance:</b>           $userinfo->bankbalance </br>";
```

}

Comment: where are you setting `$id` -> `$updateinfo->bindParam(':id', $id,     PDO::PARAM_INT);`? Should it be `$sessionid`?

Comment: yes, it should've been $sessionid.. it was a typo, thanks for catching it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of constantly hitting the database with multiple queries, consider to do it at once like this

```sql
UPDATE bank t JOIN 
(
  SELECT id, bankaccount, 
  (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
      FROM bank
     WHERE id = b.id
       AND bankbalance > b.bankbalance
  ) + 1 rank
    FROM bank b
   WHERE id = 1
) s 
   ON t.id = s.id
  AND t.bankaccount = s.bankaccount
  SET t.bankaccountranking = rank;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e61b65/1)** demo

or with two statements, leveraging user variables and `ORDER BY` in `UPDATE`

```sql
SET @rnum = 0;
UPDATE bank
   SET bankaccountranking = (@rnum := @rnum + 1)
 WHERE id = 1
 ORDER BY bankbalance DESC;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/87052/1)** demo

---

Now php code might look like this

```php
$sessionid = $_SESSION['uid'];

$sql = "UPDATE bank t JOIN 
(
  SELECT id, bankaccount, 
  (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
      FROM bank
     WHERE id = b.id
       AND bankbalance > b.bankbalance
  ) + 1 rank
    FROM bank b
   WHERE id = :id
) s 
   ON t.id = s.id
  AND t.bankaccount = s.bankaccount
  SET t.bankaccountranking = rank;";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $sessionid , PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
```

---

**UPDATE:** to implement equivalent of `DENSE_RANK()` analytic function with a subquery you can do

```sql
UPDATE bank t JOIN 
(
  SELECT id, bankaccount, 
  (
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT bankbalance)
      FROM bank
     WHERE id = b.id
       AND bankbalance > b.bankbalance
  ) + 1 rank
    FROM bank b
   WHERE id = 1
) s 
   ON t.id = s.id
  AND t.bankaccount = s.bankaccount
  SET t.bankaccountranking = rank;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fbfa1/1)** demo

or with user(session) variables

```sql
SET @r = 0, @b = NULL; 
UPDATE bank b JOIN
(
  SELECT id, bankaccount, @r := IF(@b = bankbalance, @r, @r + 1) rank, @b := bankbalance
    FROM bank
   WHERE id = 1
   ORDER BY bankbalance DESC
) s
    ON b.id = s.id
   AND b.bankaccount = s.bankaccount
   SET bankaccountranking = rank;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bf536/1)** demo

Comment: Hi Peter. Thanks for the code. One quick question... When two bank accounts have the same balance, it just ranked the bank accounts alphabetically rather than giving them both the same ranks. Example: Ben has a bank balance of $400. Tony has a bank balance of $400. The code would display Ben as ranked 1 and Tony as ranked 2 even though they both have the same balance. How would I set it so it will show them both ranked 1?

Comment: @user3063143 You're quite welcome. See updated answer.

Comment: Hi Peter thanks for the code and it updates correctly showing both bank accounts having the same ranks if both bank balances have the same amount...One problem left is when I load the page, the rankings are still alphabetically ranked for tied bank balances instead of showing rank 1 for both bank accounts.. I suspect this having to do with my the code I posted in my OP on the top page, since thats the code I used for the display page... Can you please show me how I can set the code so that it display the same rankings for tied bank balances? thanks in advance